# PHP, simplexml and foreach

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

This is my first time asking a question here, and I am also a novice at PHP and simple XML, but am determined to learn this.

the problem: my 1st foreach works fab....

the 2nd one dupes the publiccss.tpl into both dirs and ignore the other 2.....

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($target_path);
if($xml['product'] == 'style'){
$sname =                                 str_replace(' ','_',$xml['sname']);
$vers = $xml['version'];
$sp = 'library/templates/'.$sname;
if($i = mysql_query("INSERT INTO skins VALUES ('". mysql_insert_id() ."','". str_replace('_',' ',$sname) ."','". $vers ."','".$sp."')")){
if(!is_dir($sp)) mkdir($sp,0777);
foreach($xml->templategroup as $dir){
$dir = str_replace(' ','_',$dir['name']);
$p = 'library/templates/'.$sname.'/'.$dir;
if(!is_dir($p)) mkdir($p,0777);
foreach($xml->templategroup->template as $tpl){
$p = 'library/templates/'.$sname.'/'.$dir.'/'.str_replace(' ','_',$tpl['name']);            
$fp = fopen($p,"wb");
fwrite($fp,$tpl);
fclose($fp);
}
}
}else{
echo mysql_error();
}
}else{
echo 'Not a style';
}
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<style sname="DSkin" version="1.0.0" product="style">
<templategroup name="CSS Templates">
<template name="PublicCSS.tpl" date="" username="Andy?">
#body{}
</template>
</templategroup>
<templategroup name="Forum Home">
<template name="Forumhome.tpl" date="" username="Andy?">
Main index page.
</template>
<template name="Forumhome_L.tpl" date="" username="Andy?">
Level one forums.       
</template>

</templategroup>
</style>    $xml = simplexml_load_file($target_path);
if($xml['product'] == 'style'){
$sname =                                 str_replace(' ','_',$xml['sname']);
$vers = $xml['version'];
$sp = 'library/templates/'.$sname;
if($i = mysql_query("INSERT INTO skins VALUES ('". mysql_insert_id() ."','". str_replace('_',' ',$sname) ."','". $vers ."','".$sp."')")){
if(!is_dir($sp)) mkdir($sp,0777);
foreach($xml->templategroup as $dir){
$dir = str_replace(' ','_',$dir['name']);
$p = 'library/templates/'.$sname.'/'.$dir;
if(!is_dir($p)) mkdir($p,0777);
foreach($xml->templategroup->template as $tpl){
$p = 'library/templates/'.$sname.'/'.$dir.'/'.str_replace(' ','_',$tpl['name']);            
$fp = fopen($p,"wb");
fwrite($fp,$tpl);
fclose($fp);
}
}
}else{
echo mysql_error();
}
}else{
echo 'Not a style';
}
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<style sname="DSkin" version="1.0.0" product="style">
<templategroup name="CSS Templates">
<template name="PublicCSS.tpl" date="" username="Andy?">
#body{}
</template>
</templategroup>
<templategroup name="Forum Home">
<template name="Forumhome.tpl" date="" username="Andy?">
Main index page.
</template>
<template name="Forumhome_L.tpl" date="" username="Andy?">
Level one forums.       
</template>

</templategroup>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written the second loop is going back to the root of the document, and SimpleXML doesn't know which `templategroup` you want, so it assumes you just want the first one:

```
$xml->templategroup->template
```

is the same as:

```
$xml->templategroup[0]->template
```

You want to loop over all the `template` elements in the *current* `templategroup` from the outer loop, which you've called `$dir`, so what you actually want ought to be this:

```
foreach($dir->template as $tpl){
```

However, you're overwriting the variable `$dir` further down, with this line:

```
$dir = str_replace(' ','_',$dir['name']);
```

It's generally a bad idea to use the same variable for two different purposes, and in this case, `$dir` isn't really a good name for the first purpose, so I suggest you change it to:

```
foreach($xml->templategroup as $templategroup){
```

And:

```
$dir = str_replace(' ','_',$templategroup['name']);
```

Giving you an inner loop of:

```
foreach($templategroup->template as $tpl){
```

Comment: Now i;m see-ing: 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\chris\admin.php on line 66

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chris\admin.php on line 66

Comment: @ChrisJamesReynolds Ah, you're overwriting the variable `$dir`; see edited answer. You should be able to work it out from there - the key to debugging is understanding the logic.

Comment: @MMSoP, u are A genious thanx, it's works. but it dupes publiccss still, why?